# How can I generate a list of numbers which are not divisible by 3 in Scheme?

Tags: list, filter, scheme

I am trying to generate a list of numbers which are not divisible by any number I pick and I should use `filter` procedure, but I don't know how to use with 2 procedure `zero?` and `remainder.` Here are my trials:

```
(define (remove-divisible lst value)
  (filter zero? (remainder lst value)))
```

or

```
(define (remove-divisible lst value)
  (filter (zero? (remainder value)) lst))
```

but apparently, I get error because of the structure of filter procedure. How can I use it properly?

Comment: I found solution on my own :) I did not know that we can define lambda expressions in filter body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `filter` is a function that decides whether an element is to be preserved or filtered.

In your case, the function should return `#t` for numbers not divisible by given value and `#f` for numbers divisible by it.

Here's a helper function to generate such functions as required:

```
(define (not-divisible-by divisor)
  (lambda (dividend)
    (not (zero? (remainder dividend divisor)))))
```

Now, defining the function you need is simple:

```
(define (remove-divisible lst value)
  (filter (not-divisible-by value) lst))
```

Of course, you can skip the helper function if you so desire:

```
(define (remove-divisible lst value)
  (filter (lambda (x) (not (zero? (remainder x value)))) lst))
```

I would recommend using the more readable approach though.